# How to generate random numbers in the same line with Js?

Tags: javascript

I have an algorithm that simulates a lottery generating numbers from 1 to 50 and numbers from 1 to 10. For this, I'm using a Math function and a for loop to code this lottery.

My problem is to find a way for my result to come out in one line instead of new lines. I'll explain with some code:

```
for (let rand_num = 1; rand_num <= 5; rand_num++) {
    console.log("Numbers")
    console.log(Math.floor(Math.random() * 50) + 1);
}

for (let rand_star = 1; rand_star <= 2; rand_star++) {
    console.log("Stars")
    console.log(Math.floor(Math.random() * 10) + 1);
}
```

**Output:**

Numbers

10

Numbers

8...

Stars

2

Stars

7...

As this output takes up too much space I would like another alternative that leaves random values in the same line like this output example:
**Output:**

Numbers: 10 - 8 - 50 - 44 - 21

Stars: 2 - 7

Comment: so build a string, do not console.log each one.

Comment: Your lottery is *unusual* at best. I've never seen a "lottery" in which the same numbers are eventually repeated.

Comment: Yeah I know it's just for learning purposes :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always create a reusable function to generate the random numbers and place them into an array. Then return those numbers separated by your seperator.

```js
function lotteryNumbers(max, total) {
  let nums = [];
  for (let x = 1; x <= total; x++) {
    nums.push(Math.floor(Math.random() * max) + 1);
  }
  return nums.join(" - ");
}

console.log("Numbers: " + lotteryNumbers(50, 5));
console.log("Stars: " + lotteryNumbers(10, 2));
```